# ios detect if UILabel consist all text

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel, nsattributedstring

How can I detect if my `UILabel` contain all text, that I insert in it?
My `UILabel` use autolayout sizeToFit, can have different numbers of line, and I use attributedString for this Label with different parameters include `NSParagraphStyle`?

Comment: @TotumusMaximus: this questions have nothing in common. The other question is about finding a sub string, while this is about checking, if all text is displayed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903772/how-to-find-out-width-of-truncated-uilabel-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using storyboards, you can go to attributes inspector and choose: "Minimum Font Size" and specify that value...this way if the text that has to be on the label is to big to the size of it, it will shrink...I don´t know if you are using storyboards or not but this is working for me.

Regards